# react-redux state is changing but display is stills same (no re-render)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i've been working on a project trying to learn redux with react. But there is an error and i don't know exactly how to fix it. Files/codes in down if you need more information about how store works.

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [thunk]

const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()))

export default store;
```

**actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios"

export const increment = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: 'INCREMENT',
        payload: payload
    }
}

export const decrement = () => {
    return {
        type: 'DECREMENT'
    }
}

export const fetch = () => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
        .then(data => dispatch({type: 'FETCH', payload: data.data}))    
    }
}
```

**store/todos.js**

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH':
            return Object.assign(state, action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default todos;
```

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {useSelector, useDispatch, connect} from 'react-redux'
import {increment, decrement, fetch} from './store/actions/'
import { GeistProvider, CssBaseline } from '@geist-ui/react';

function App(props) {
  const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter)
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>Count is {count}</h1>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(3))}>+</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>-</button>
          <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetch())}>FETCH</button>
          {todos.length ? todos[0].title : <h1>Not fetched.</h1>}
        </header>
      </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

This is the codes in project. Let me know if you guys need more information about anything. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong at `return Object.assign(state, action.payload);`. It's mutated `state` so redux can't detect state change. You should read this https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions

You can change to this

`return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);`

or this

`return { ...state, ...action.payload }`

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but component still doesn't re-render. Render is still looks with "Not fetched."

Comment: @schwarzsky Did you check the data return from API. maybe it's empty.

Comment: Yep, i checked the data. Data is an array with 100 todos.